# JBL Quantum 100 headphones making weird popping noise on Minecraft: Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, audio-hardware

Once in a while, I like to play Bedrock Minecraft (PvP purposes). For some reason though, my headphones (JBL Quantum 100) makes a very weird and especially annoying popping sound in the game. This does not happen with any other headphones and it only happens on Bedrock Edition.

Is there a way to get around this? (***Note***: They are only about four (4) months old.)